# Chrome extension disables js triggers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, dom-events

I have made a little Chrome extension that injects some code in the current page.
This extension has a weird behaviour though, whenever the code is injected, none of the page's Javascript triggers seem to work anymore.

Would one of you have any idea what that happens? On  top of fixing the code I'd really like to know why this happens.

Example : on this page : http://www.acti.fr/success-story/ghd/ if the extension injects the picture, I cannot click on either the menu or "continuer la lecture" at the bottom.

Here are the manifest and the actual code :

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

        "name": "wpi",
        "description": "just an other extension",
        "version": "1.0",
        "content_scripts": [{
            "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
            "js": ["my-style.js"]
        }]
}
```

my-script.js :

```
function wpkm_check_content(wpkm_text) {
    var wpkm_word = wpkm_text.split(" ");
    var wpkm_c = wpkm_word[0].localeCompare("Wordpress");
    if (wpkm_c == 1)
        return (1);
    return (0);
}
var wpkm_html = '<div id="wpkm-bloc" style="position:absolute;right:10px;top:10px;z-index:99999">';
wpkm_html += '<img id="wpkm-img" src="https://nathanarnold.files.wordpress.com/2009/02/ssim51.gif">';
wpkm_html += '</div>';
var wpkm_sdomain = document.domain;
var wpkm_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
wpkm_request.open('GET', '/license.txt', true);
wpkm_request.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (wpkm_request.readyState === 4){
        if (wpkm_request.status === 200
                && wpkm_check_content(wpkm_request.responseText) == 1) {
            document.body.innerHTML += wpkm_html;
        }
        else {
            console.log("Oh no, it does not exist!");
        }
    }
};
wpkm_request.send();
```

Any hints will be appreciated :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're effectively reassigning the *entire* innerHTML of the document body by using `+=` append operator which causes reevaluation and recreation of the entire page and of course all previously attached event handlers aren't reattached automatically.

Use [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) instead:

```
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", wpkm_html);
```

Comment: Thank you ever so much, that's a very valuable piece of information you've just shared !